# Не открываются сайты по локальному ip

Tags: debian, config

После обновления мои проекты на node js перестали открываться по локальному ip адресу(нет не локалхост) c других устройств, но на ноуте с которого я запускаю всё работает фаервол не использую.

```sh
npm run dev -- --host // тож не помогает
```

мой хостс файл

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   h1.org h1
#127.0.1.1  deb1.org deb1
#127.0.0.1   mainflask.net www.mainflask.net
#1.2.3.4         account.jetbrains.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
#192.168.250.1 master-node
#192.168.250.2 worker-node
```

обновился с debian 11 на 12
Есть возможная догадка что я при обновлении согласился заменить какой-то старый конфиг на новый (но я не помню какой),может было у кого-так?
Что с этим можно сделать в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл это решение
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552857/why-are-my-network-connections-being-rejected

Оказывается я включил при обновлении firewalld
И да проблема решается этой командой:

```
systemctl disable --now firewalld
```